# How to allow NULL values (Loading pandas dataframe into MS SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, pandas, null

My current codes can only load full dataframe into SQL server tables.
If there are some NULL values in the column OpSeq. How can I change my current codes to accept NULL values.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

# Import CSV
data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\moin\Desktop\MM\XXK.csv')   
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns['Order','Number','Group','ActualStartDate','ActualCompletionDate','OpSeq'])

# Connect to SQL Server
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                  'Server=XXXXXXX\SQLEXPRESS;'
                  'Database=test_XXXXXproduction;'
                  'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Create Table
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE people_info (Order nvarchar(50), Number nvarchar(50), 
Group nvarchar(50), ActualStartDate datetime, ActualCompletionDate datetime, OpSeq int)')

# Insert DataFrame to Table
for row in df.itertuples():
cursor.execute('''
            INSERT INTO test_preproduction.dbo.people_info (Order, Number, Group, ActualStartDate, ActualCompletionDate, OpSeq)
            VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)
            ''',
            row.Order, 
            row.Number,
            row.Group,
            row.ActualStartDate,
            row.ActualCompletionDate,
            row.OpSeq
            )
 conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

your code should work depending on how you pass null

, you can pass NULL as NaN or None or 'null'